# JSON to NSDictionary to Dictionary

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, nsdictionary, nsurlsession

I am trying to pass an API server response to Dictionary so I can later iterate values for keys. I understand it is a common problem, so I expect best and common practices here.
Building on a Jameson Quave's POST Tutorial I am connecting to API via POST and trying to make a structured data (a Dict) from a data received (excluding headers and server response). I have seen and tried other examples on NSURLSession, this one because of POST and response JSON content.

Part of Swift code for structuring a response:

```
        var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        println("Response: \(response)")

        var strData = NSDictionary.self
        println("Body: \(strData)")
```

See the part "var strData = .."?
Here I tried "as Dictionary" or "= NSDictionary(objectsAndKeys: data) as Dictionary" or "= NSDictionary(object: data, forKey: NSDictionary.self)" just to get more errors.

It sure works well with ".. = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)" and I get a string, which works ok, but I need a dic to iterate. Later on I can learn more on generics and apply common rules to received content in various situations to build a proper code. But right now I feel as I am researching law in Britain from 12 century. Sorry for my bad sarcasm here, but marketing "Should be simple ObjC without a C" does not seem to apply here, plus "NSStuff" really gives me a feel like an extra luggage from old days in a modern Swift code.:)

Back from my python days it was fairly simple, like:

```
myresponse = requests.request('POST',url,data=json.dumps(payload))
myvariable = u'data'
mydata = json.loads(myresponse.content)
```

and it's done! I have a mydata Dict. Simple with less code.

I know I am missing a point here. Plus a dict in JSON data does contain nested dicts (no clue if it's handled in Swift case). 
I would be thankful for pieces of code etc and a common practice in case on handling JSON data from API's. The proper way to do it. Thanks!